# Removing leading zeros from month and day

Tags: postgresql, date-format

Someone in a PostgreSQL chat room gave me this syntax.  It is used in a `VIEW` that outputs an RSS feed link:

```
to_char(tips_chronic_pain_weekly_selection.start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD'::text)
Example output: 2021/09/13
```

I am not familiar with how this works.  Am I able to remove the leading **0** in both month and day? This was given to me several months ago as a shorten version of:

```
concat( extract( YEAR FROM tips_physical_disability_weekly_selection.start_date), '/',  extract( MONTH FROM tips_physical_disability_weekly_selection.start_date), '/',  extract( DAY FROM tips_physical_disability_weekly_selection.start_date) )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `FM` format modifier:

```sql
to_char(tips_chronic_pain_weekly_selection.start_date, 'YYYY/FMMM/FMDD'::text)
```

This modifies suppresses leading zeros and padding spaces.

Comment: Thank you.  I was searching for removing leading zero.  Is the `to_char` the function that formats dates?

Comment: @RonPiggott Depends on parameters datatypes. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html